# For $u$ harmonic and positive in $B(0,R)$, we have $R^{n-1}\frac{R+|x|}{(R-|x|)^{n-1}}u(0) \le u(x) \le R^{n-1} \frac{R - |x|}{(R + |x|)^{n-1}} u(0)$

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

This was an exercise in my functional analysis course: Let $B := B(0, R) \subset \mathbb R^n$, $u$ harmonic and positive. We have to show that
$$R^{n-1} \frac{R + |x|}{(R - |x|)^{n-1}}u(0) \le u(x) \le R^{n-1} \frac{R - |x|}{(R + |x|)^{n-1}} u(0)$$
for all $x \in B$.

I do not really see how to begin. I only found that for all $x \in B$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \varepsilon) \subset B$ so that
\begin{align*}
u(x) &= \frac{c_n}{\varepsilon^n} \int_{B(x, \varepsilon)} u(y)dy\\
&\le \left(\frac{R}{\varepsilon}\right)^n\frac{c_n}{R^n} \int_{B} u(y)dy\\
&= \left(\frac{R}{\varepsilon}\right)^nu(0)
\end{align*}
but I do not see how continue from here. Any help is welcome!

Comment: This looks like Harnack's inequality.

Comment: Do you know about the Poisson kernel representation in a ball?